Selenium Python: Fail to use ARROW_DOWN to select a specific auto-suggest dropdown element
I am learning how to use Selenium Python to implement auto-suggest dropdown.
I have mastered using for-loop to select a desired element, but I also want to learn how to use ARROW_DOWN to perform the same task.
I have tried:
method 1: send_keys(Key.ARROW_DOWN * 6)
and
Method 2. for i in range(0, 10):
Can anyone advise me how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance.
       #Code:


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
from time import sleep

driver.get('https://www.yatra.com/flights')
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(2)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#Click "I Agree" cookies policy button
try:
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'I Agree')]"))).click()
  sleep(1)
except NoSuchElementException:
  print("No Cookies Agree button!")

#Find "Depart From" edit box
depart_from = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "BE_flight_origin_city")))
depart_from.click()
sleep(1)

depart_from.clear()

#input partial city name "New"
#The desired city: New Plymouth
depart_from.send_keys('New', Keys.ARROW_DOWN * 6)
sleep(1)

print("From:", depart_from.get_attribute('value'))  # return string entered

#I have also tried
for i in range(0, 10):
  depart_from.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
  if "New Plymouth" in depart_from.text:
    depart_from.click()
break
  


I am also facing same issue. Have you find the solution?. Please share me

Finally able to select using selenium mouse and hold command
